# Laravel Get the translations of the application from a package

Tags: laravel

I am trying to develop a small package in `Laravel`, but I have the following problem. From my package I need to get the translations that are present in the languages directory:

Example:

```
myapp/resources/lang
```

When I make a call as follows to get the translations of a file:

```
    private function getTranslationsFromFile()
    {
        return Lang::get('auth');
    }
```

It does not return the translations in that file. It only returns `auth`. In the Laravel languages directory there is that file, but inside the directory `en`.

So I have defined before getting the translations the default `'locale'` so that I can load them from there in this way:

```
    private function getTranslationsFromFile()
    {
        app()->setLocale('en');
        
        return Lang::get('auth');
    }
```

this way it works fine, but my question is the following, is there no way to load the translations regardless of whether or not the `'locale'` is set? I mean, is it not possible to get the translations just by giving it a file path?

Example:

```
    private function getTranslationsFromFile()
    {        
        return Lang::get('en/auth');
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do that by leveraging the third and fourth parameter of [`Lang::get()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.html#method_get):

This is the method's signature:

```
get(string $key, array $replace = [], string|null $locale = null, bool $fallback = true)
```

The third parameter specifies the locale you'd wish to get the translation string for:

```
Lang::get('auth.failed', [], 'en')
```

To set a fallback language in case that the translation is not available in the chosen locale, use the fourth parameter:

```
Lang::get('auth.failed', [], 'en', 'es')
```